# In App update not working for app bundle apk

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, in-app-update

I have implemented recently launched In-App update API in my android app. When I build apk and test this functionality it works fine. ( I have uploaded apk with higher version with beta track). But when I build app bundle and upload the app bundle to internal internal app sharing , App update dialog is never prompted. (same source code only difference is in first case apk and in second case via app bundle).

Comment: I am not sure, but might the issue is because of the app keystore. You need to add you release keystore fingerprint.

Comment: so I am creating signed app bundle with the same production key-store.

Comment: is there any solution yet for it?

Comment: Is it a debug build or a release build? Sometimes proguard creates differences between them...

Comment: its release build

Comment: have you found any solution yet ? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

In-App updates are not yet supported with internal app sharing.

We are working on this, but do not yet have a timeframe for completion of this feature.

**Update: Internal App sharing now supports testing In-app updates.**

By visiting an Internal App Sharing link with a higher version code (but not installing it yet), an app that you already installed through Internal app sharing 'learns' of the new version, which allows you to test the in-app update flow.

Comment: will it work for app bundle apk uploaded to beta channel on play-store?

Comment: Yes. You can also test in-app updates with the internal test track.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the new app bundle format for in-app updates? Or does it work with plain old APKs?

Comment: yesterday for the first time we have used app bundle for production release. But after this release users of the existing version could not see in-app update dialog. This is really strange and I can't enforce users force update. Whats the issue here?

Comment: Can you please reach out to 'Play Console > Help > Contact Us' ? We would need to investigate this issue for your specific developer account.

Comment: Does it already work with internal app sharing? I mean [this thing presented at Dev Summit 19](https://youtu.be/_o_q6hatcIs?t=469)

Comment: Yes, In-app updates now work with Internal app sharing, I updated my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In app update works only if you have uploaded app-bundle to production track on play store. As mentioned by Serge Beauchamp, it will not work for internal app sharing. During my last production release, I have uploaded app-bundle instead of apk. Initially I could not see in-app update dialog may be for first 1-2 hours. But when I tried again on next day, I could see in-app update dialog. My suggestion is if your release is mandatory, implement fallback mechanism for update. In case play store refuses to show in-app update available, show your own dialog where you can redirect user to play-store to update app.  You can use below code for fallback mechanism

```
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))  {
     //play store says update available. In App update dialog will be displayed
} else {
    //its mandatory release but play store says no update available ,
    // show custom UI to redirect to play store
}
```