# How to test In App Update In Android Manually

Tags: android, testing, manual-testing, app-update, in-app-update

I have implemented In-app update in my app and followed the below mentioned steps to test it,

1. Uninstall the original app from device.
2. Install the app from the Google Play Store
3. Uninstall the app again.
4. Generate signed apk with the new feature, with a lower versionCode than Google Play version
   Install this apk.

Above mentioned steps will not work in some devices.

So I want to know if there is any alternative way for this testing.

Comment: Lowering the version code does not work. I had success with pushing two consecutive versions to Internal App Sharing. Check this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266778/15139

Answer (score 3):

At the end of [the document](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates), you should make sure the below conditions:

[image]

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the in app update feature their are some pre requirements , you need to make sure that the application is already live and installed in your device  , one user is already logged In  into the app and their is an update coming soon for that app.
For testing the in app update feature of the android application the user needs to follow various steps:

Step - 1 Verify that the app you are testing is live on play store.

Step - 2 Install the application

Step - 3 Login to the app.

Step - 4 Ask the developer to upload the latest build

Step - 5 Open playstore and check whether their is any update for the app.

Step - 6 If their is an update on playstore , Open your app and check for the app update pop up.